# How is input in react being handled?

Tags: reactjs

**    I think I just struggle with this long enough to ask here...so what is the difference between onChange and value here in the input element? To me it seems that both are setting the term to the input text**

```
class SubmitForm extends React.Component {
  state = { term: '' };
  render() {
    return(
      <form>
        <input 
          type='text'
          className='input'
          placeholder='Enter Item'
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({term: e.target.value})}
        />
        <button className='button'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `value` presents the value, it doesn't change it.  Hardcode it to something else and you'll see that it no longer changes.

Answer (score 0):

`value` is the value of the input text box to the letter. when you are trying to update the input text box, `onChange` event will be emitted and here, you should update the variable that indicates `value`.

If you don't specify onChange event, input textbox is not updated even though you press any key because input box `value` is always indicated with the same value - this.state.term.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to reactJS, the value attribute on an html input is what the current `value` of the input is, the `onChange` attribute does something (in your case updating the state thus updating the value) whenever the a change happens to the input.